# слайдер swiper при скроллинге страницы оказывается "над" закрепленным headerом

Tags: header, swiper, fixed

Всем привет! Я новичок в вёрстке и делаю свой первый сайт) Было необходимо закрепить header, с чем я справился без проблем. Но вот беда - слайдер, находящийся сразу под headerом "залазит" на него при прокрутке страницы)

Answer (score 0):

z-index решил все мои проблемы)